# Paperclip: "Image has an extension that does not match its contents"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a `Product` model with an attachment:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:basename.:extension"

validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image,
                                  :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

However, regardless of what kind of file I try to upload, validation fails with the message

> Image has an extension that does not match its contents

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you give answers in comments?? You answer is corrent anyway

Comment: @janfoeh it rise the error `Missing template products/create` and does not write to db

Comment: That's a different problem. Could you please add your `create` controller method to your question? Or even better, add your full controller.

Comment: You probably have a validation problem. `@product` does not save, so your `create` method does not redirect and tries to do the default action instead - render a template named `create`. Try using `@product.save!` instead of `@product.save` to have it throw an exception; this makes it easier to see why it does not save.

Comment: @janfoeh Validation failed: Image has an extension that does not match its contents

Comment: Seems like you're trying to upload something as an image that isn't really an image. See [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations) for more info.

Comment: @janfoeh no. All on all files it rises this error

Comment: Do you have a `validates_attachment_content_type` in your `Product` model? Which version of Paperclip do you use? Please add the part of your `Product` model that is relevant to Paperclip (such as `has_attached_file`, validations etc).

Comment: @railsr because by now I have a pretty good hunch whenever there's more to the story. As it is this time, as you can see.

Comment: @janfoeh I did add to the question

Comment: What version of Paperclip do you use?

Comment: @janfoeh paperclip 4.2

Comment: Can you please post the server log file entries that are added when you try and upload an image?

Answer (score 1):

In you case you should use `image` value for file input name:

```
<%= form.file_field :image %>
```

and permit :image field instead of :image_file_name:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:slug_en, :image)
```

Comment: it rise the error Missing template products/create and does not write to db

Comment: Seems like `@product.save` return false. Try to change it to `@product.save!` and you will see a reason of problem with save in logs.

Comment: Validation failed: Image has an extension that does not match its contents

Comment: Seems like you are using Windows. In this case your latest problem described [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file).